# Traverse up until some element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-traversing

I have some element selected with jQuery selector. It is en element from list of elements with the same class ('my-elements'). Now I'd like to select element containing the selected one which is several levels above. How can I do this ?

```
<div class="vote>
(... several levels)
<div class="my_element"></div>
</div>
```

the selector:

```
var elements = $('.my_element');
var element = elements[0];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `.closest()` method should work (http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
elements.closest("div.vote");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly you want to traverse to div.votes from div.my_element
Try this:

```
var elements = $('.my_element'); 
var element = elements.closest("div.vote");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to find the container element for your current object I suggest the `parents()` method.  It takes a selector, or without one, returns all of the parents of the element.