# Is there a method in jQuery that will traverse up the dom tree from an element and check selectors before its parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example:

```
<div class="mainWrapper">
    <div class="FirstLayer">
        <input class="foo" value="foo" />
    </div>

    <div class="SecondLayer">
        <div class="thirdLayer">
            <input class="fee" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lets say I have the `input.fee` as a jQuery object and I also need to get the value of `input.foo`.
Now I know I can use a multitude of approaches such as `$(this).parents(':eq(2)').find('.foo')` but I want to use this one method on layouts which will have varying levels and numbers of nodes.
So I am wondering if there is a method which will simply start from `.fee` and just keep going up until it finds the first matching element, `.prevAll()` does not appear to do this. There are many `.foo` and `.fee` elements and I need specifically the first one above the `.fee` in context.

Comment: Could you show an example with multiple `foo` and `fee` fields as the traversal will most likely be different

Comment: You can use `closest` method, `$(this).closest('.mainWrapper').find('.foo')`

Comment: Going up will never reach `foo`, because it isn't an ancestor of `fee`. It is a sibling of an ancestor of `fee`

Comment: @Asad So there is not a function that will simply go up the dom tree checking all elements for a class, irrespective if ancestor or not?

Comment: @LaserBeak Right. It's called tree for a reason - you can't traverse up and expect to reach all the _branches_ and _leafs_ of a tree.

Comment: @LaserBeak `going up the dom tree` means iterating over the ancestors of the element. See raina77ow answer, in which he iterates over all ancestors, filters out the ones that contain your desired element, and finds the element in that ancestor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Traverse up until some element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198259/traverse-up-until-some-element)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('input.fee').closest(':has("input.foo")')
              .find('input.foo').val();
```

Here's [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YZ6vg/3/) to play with. )

UPDATE: Kudos to @VisioN - of course, `parents:first` is well replaced by `closest`.

Comment: Instead of applying `:first` selector you'd better use `closest()` method.

Comment: @VisioN But of course. ) Was confused by that `:has` selector.

Comment: Great, I was stuck because didn't think of `:has` instead I was wrongly trying with `.closest('* input.foo')` +1 for a well played answer :-)

Comment: This will not pick the previous div with input.foo. Look at fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YZ6vg/4/). I think it might traverse through parents but when matching them against a selector it must start at parent with index 0.

Comment: @Bruno Yes, IMO the best solution for this would qualify for a new jquery method, could be called .nearest() , that would traverse back doing .prev() checking for selector and when there's no more prev() it goes to parent() and continue doing prev() again.

Comment: @Nelson I gave an answer to this question that traverses up to elements under .mainWrapper and finds previous div that contains input.foo. That should work.

Comment: @Bruno I think your solution is too localized to this specific html layout, while OP stated wanted a general solution that would work for, citing him `on layouts which will have varying levels and numbers of nodes`

Comment: @Bruno I gave you upvote not for your answer but for providing here a fiddle that would show how the accepted answer won't fully work in all conditions (so not resolving the general problem in full either).

Comment: @Nelson amended solution to handle varying levels of nodes :)

Answer (score 1):

This will select the previous input.foo

```
// self might have siblings that are input.foo so include in selection
$( $("input.fee").parentsUntil(":has(input.foo)").andSelf()

        // if input.off is sibling of input.fee then nothing will
        // be returned from parentsUntil. This is the only time input.fee
        // will be selected by last(). Reverse makes sure self is at index 0
        .get().reverse() )

        // last => closest element
        .last()                 

        //fetch siblings that contain or are input.foo elements
        .prevAll(":has(input.foo), input.foo") 

        // first is closest
        .first() 

        // return jQuery object with all descendants
        .find("*")         

        // include Self in case it is an input.foo element 
        .andSelf() 

        .filter("input.foo")

        // return value of first matching element
        .val()
```

Comment: This won't work if having an element between .firstlayer and .secondlayer see http://jsfiddle.net/YZ6vg/7/  And it would not also work in this scenario http://jsfiddle.net/YZ6vg/8/

Comment: This answer is practically as good as the accepted one, just each one handle different layout corner cases better than the other, but for any both answers a layout can easily be done so that they fail. I repeat the general solution for finding a *nearest* element would be to create a new jquery method that would combine prev() with parent() as described in my comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: Wow, excellent work with your last version, it passed all fiddles so far but I still found it failing for this one http://jsfiddle.net/YZ6vg/16/

Comment: @Nelson I know I won't get any more points :) but any chance of checking the above works. If it is too much work don't bother but just out of interest.

Comment: Yes, your final version is working for all fiddles posted so far, congratulations :-)

Comment: @Thanks Nelson. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score -1):

[`jQuery.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) takes selector and does exactly what you need - finds the first matching element that is parent of something. There's also [jQuery.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) that does take a selector to filter element ancestors. Use those combined with `find` method and you're set.

`$('input.fee').closest('.mainWrapper").find('.foo')` does the trick, doesn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately not really exactly what he needs.

Comment: But `foo` isn't a parent of `fee` it's a child of a parent.

Comment: Didn't downvote you, but the `closest` should be used here only with combination of `:has` - it traverses up the DOM tree, but does not look down at each step. )